indentation dissapeared inside <ul><li> after <br>
Normally:


<ul>
  <li>first list item<br>
  <li>second list item<br>
  a little something about this one..</li>
  <li>third list item<br>
</ul>



would display on page something like:
· first list item
· second list item
  a little something about this one...
· third list item

However, after taking some layout advice I have a problem, which is no doubt because of the line added to my css of:


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
<ul>
  <li>first list item<br>
  <li>second list item<br>
  a little something about this one..</li>
  <li>third list item<br>
</ul>



anyway now I get the same code displaying with the line indent removed after the br:
· first list item
· second list item
a little something about this one...
· third list item

is there a way to put this back, whithout removing the * { margin: 0; padding: 0; } from my stylesheet? i.e. restoring the inherited indentation?
I have tried a few different things like adding br { margin: inherit; } etc and been searching online and here, but...

That approach is correct one.  You just need apply margin and padding to ul and li.

ul has a padding-left by default, and that's where the bullet points are shown. So just give it some padding-left again ...

well, br { padding-left: 50px; } or br { padding-left: inherit; } don't do anything...

ul {   list-style-position: outside;   padding-left: 20px;  }
